# Intellij does not save local history for unknown file types?

Tags: intellij-idea

I include a scala REPL startup/config file in my source tree and name it `.scalarc`:

[image]

Many edits have been made in the past 24 hours and in fact significant ones just within the last few minutes. However the right click /context popup for `Local History` has the `Show History` option as disabled:

[image]

Is there a way to enable the history for *all* file types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and added `.scalarc` as a `*.scala` file:

[image]

Now the `local history` does show up:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly a reason why local history is disabled, e.g. for `groovy` in PyCharm. You need to define a "new" file type.